# Routing in Rails fails when changing application to Multilingual Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

I am fairly new to Rails and have been unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.
Wondering if someone can help?
I have a Rails application that is working without problems, that is before I started modifications to make it multilingual.

To make it multilingual I have taken the following steps:

I added this to the routing file:
    scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|is/ do

Routing file:

```
PropertyEvaluator::Application.routes.draw do  
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|is/ do  
    root :to => "pages#home"  

    get 'pages/about'  
    get 'pages/home'  

    get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"  
    get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"  
    get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"  

    resources :searches, :only => [:index, :new, :create]  
    resources :users, :only =>  [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]  
    resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]  
    resources :password_resets, :only =>  [:new, :create, :edit, :update]  
    resources :email_activations, :only => [:edit]   
    resources :roles, :only => [:edit, :update]  
  end  
end
```

Routing file before modificaions:

```
PropertyEvaluator::Application.routes.draw do  
  root :to => "pages#home"  

  get 'pages/about'  
  get 'pages/home'  

  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"  
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"  
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"  

  resources :searches, :only => [:index, :new, :create]  
  resources :users, :only =>  [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]  
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]  
  resources :password_resets, :only =>  [:new, :create, :edit, :update]  
  resources :email_activations, :only => [:edit]  
  resources :roles, :only => [:edit, :update]  
end
```

To application_controller.rb I added

```
before_filter :set_locale  

def set_locale  
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale  
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:locale]= I18n.locale
```

To the view I added:

```
<%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :is, "IS", locale: :is %>  
|   
<%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :en, "EN", locale: :en %>
```

Things are working as expected with the original routing file, but when I add the scope to the routing file the problem starts.

I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :locale=>#<User      id: 2, email: "bjarni.sigurdsson@bodeind.is", password_hash:   "$2a$10$WzcoB5pES3TXYbWpe7xtB.yKFnqi.dhQgMXOp8/nyKi...", password_salt:  "$2a$10$WzcoB5pES3TXYbWpe7xtB.", created_at: "2014-09-30 15:20:38", updated_at: "2014-10-01 12:41:57", name: "Bjarni Sigurðsson", auth_token: "wY2cfwk-1R7fSjCvqQPaWQ", password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil, admin: true, email_confirmed: true, email_activation_token: nil,   email_confirmed_at: "2014-09-30 15:20:38", role: 4>} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Pointing to the following code in the view:

```
<%= link_to(t('views.shared.navbar.edit_user_profile'), edit_user_path(current_user), class: 'btn btn-primary') %>
```

If I remove the scope from the routing file things work but the selected locale is not displayed in the url.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine except passing a `:locale` param while path generation. Look at the exception, there's: `:locale=>#<User...`. Since `params[:locale]` is `nil`, it takes user as first arg. Extend your app controller with:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Working as expected.